# Mess with lists of variables

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

Recently I've been working on a code that saves a set of variables on a list, and each set is saved on one list that contains all the other lists of variables, then I remove some characters of the variables and transform them into float, finally I take the smallest number of each list and save it on another list. The problem is when I move those numbers to the new list it just show me one number and not the entire list. Can somebody help me?
Here's the code:

```
from typing import List
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal

ListaPreciosCromos = list()

ListaUrl = ['https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_495570&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc', 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_540190&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc', 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_607210&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc',]
PageCromos = [requests.get(x) for x in ListaUrl]
SoupCromos = [BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser") for x in PageCromos]
PrecioCromos = [x.find_all("span", {"data-price": True}) for x in SoupCromos]


for x in PrecioCromos: 
    for i in x: # 
        Cromolist2 = [h.replace("$","") for h in i] 
        CromoList3 = [h.replace("USD","") for h in Cromolist2] 
        CromoList4 = [float(h) for h in CromoList3] 
        CantidadCromos = len(CromoList4)
        CromoList5 = sorted(CromoList4) 
        CromoList6 = CromoList5[0]
print(CromoList6)
```

Output:

```
0.06
```

Comment: What do you think this line does?  `CromoList6 = CromoList5[0]`

Comment: Curious what `print(cromolist5)` looks like.

Comment: @JNevill same problem. It shows only one variable and I'm looking for more. I don't know what I'm doing wrong to get only one variable on the list.

Comment: The `for x` loop will execute 3 times, based on how many elements are in `ListaUrl`.  For each of those loop iterations, the `for i` loop will execute possibly many times, based on how many elements the `.find_all()` returned.  For each of *those* iterations, you assign a brand-new value to `CromoList6` - overwriting whatever value it might have had previously.  You then print the value from the very last iteration; all of the previous work your program did was completely wasted.  You either need to print inside the loop, or accumulate values in a list.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper!! But what if I want to keep the smallest value of each of the lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Instead of using `replace()` twice, you can use `strip(USD$)` to remove the `$` and `USD` from the string.
- You can use `min()` function to get the minimum value of list instead of sorting.

> *`min()` takes O(N) and `sorted()` takes O(NlogN) Time*.

- Since you need a list of minimum values, you need to use this

> `CromoList6.append(CromoList5[0])` -  *This appends all the minimum values to CromoList6.*

Here is a minified version of your code with above mentioned changes.

```
from typing import List
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

ListaPreciosCromos = list()

ListaUrl = ['https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_495570&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc', 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_540190&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc', 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_607210&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc',]
PageCromos = [requests.get(x) for x in ListaUrl]
SoupCromos = [BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser") for x in PageCromos]
PrecioCromos = [x.find_all("span", {"data-price": True}) for x in SoupCromos]

min_CromoList = []

for item in PrecioCromos:
    CromoList = [float(i.text.strip('USD$')) for i in item]
    min_CromoList.append(min(CromoList))

print(min_CromoList)
```

```
[0.04, 0.05, 0.05]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `CromoList6 = CromoList5[0]` to `CromoList6.append(CromoList5[0])`